# linux dot utility (with xhprof)

Tags: php, linux, profiling, graphviz

i installed the xhprof profiling extension for php

Everything is fine except for the callgraph.php file, it returns:
`failed to shell execute cmd=" dot -Tpng"`

so i checked and the dot utility wasn't installed, so i installed it.

it appears to be running fine from the command line so i ran the scritp again, same error:
`failed to shell execute cmd=" dot -Tpng"`

the xhprof documentation states:
`the callgraph image visualization ([View Callgraph]) feature relies on the presence of Graphviz "dot" utility in your path.`

but i don't understand what i need to do now, specifically the "utility in your path" part

Any help appreciated, thanks guys

Answer (score 18):

If you want graphing functions for xhprof run next command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

Comment: Also available for Mac using homebrew: `brew install graphviz`. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

When I enable error_reporting, I see there are some configuration variable are missing:

```
function xhprof_generate_image_by_dot($dot_script, $type) {
  // get config => yep really dirty - but unobstrusive
  global $_xhprof;

  $errorFile    = $_xhprof['dot_errfile'];
  $tmpDirectory = $_xhprof['dot_tempdir'];
  $dotBinary    = $_xhprof['dot_binary'];
```

After add the following lines to xhprof_lib/config.php, it works

```
$_xhprof['dot_errfile'] = '/home/peniel/var/log/xhprof/error.log';
$_xhprof['dot_tempdir'] = '/home/peniel/var/log/xhprof';
$_xhprof['dot_binary'] = '/usr/bin/dot';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed *graphviz* this error also will occure because of the security restrictions. Some functions may be disabled. So, see your logs for some php warnings.

For example:

```
PHP Warning:  proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons in /usr/share/php/xhprof_lib/utils/callgraph_utils.php on line 112
```

You need to configure *php.ini* or *security.ini* parameter "*disable_functions*".

Answer (score 0):

Having the utility "in your path" means that it can be located by the environment variable `PATH`.  This environment variables contains directories where the shell looks for binaries that you run without an explicit path.

Let's say the full path to `dot` is `/opt/foo/bin/dot`.  Then you want to modify your `PATH` environment variable this way:

```
PATH=${PATH}:/opt/foo/bin
```

Comment: i added it as you said PATH=${PATH}:/usr/bin/dot
same error (i should also say its from within a web browser)

Comment: @mononym - you need to set the PATH for your web server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused simply because graphviz was not installed. You can check with `which dot` or `locate graphviz` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

steps for fast fix the issue if you have Graphviz and still getting error:

1. run "which dot"

> /usr/local/bin/dot

2. open xhprof_lib/utils/callgraph_utils.php line 110
3. replace "dot" by "/usr/local/bin/dot" (or path you have)